# Can I share a CableModem connection via a Gigabit Switch?

Tags: networking, cable-modem

Can I configure my network this way?
It's not working (only one device has internet access)
So I was thinking that I needed to have an actual router in there to assign IP addresses to each device.

```
                                    |----- CableModem==<=cable==<==
                                    | ------  PC  
                          GigaSwitch| -------PC
                                    | -------- PC
```

[TPLink TL SG1008D](http://www.tp-link.com/us/products/details/cat-5582_TL-SG1008D.html)

Comment: Are all the devices using the same default gateway IP address as the one device that works? Are they using the same DNS server as well?

Comment: short answer, it depends on your ISPs rules and options. If your plan allows multiple public addresses, it will work. Otherwise, it depends on the cablemodem itself,  and whether it has routing features that you can use (DHCP, NAT, Firewall, etc.). if its just a dumb modem however, it won;t work unless you can pull multiple public IPs from the ISP DHCP server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official DOCSIS cable modem standards, if it's just called a cable modem, it's not a router and it latches onto the first Ethernet MAC address it sees and only talks to that one machine, at least until the cable modem is rebooted.

By the same standard, if it's called a Cable Gateway, it contains router (really NAT gateway) functionality, and supports multiple clients.

If what you have is just a cable modem and you don't want to replace it with a cable gateway, you can put any consumer home gateway router behind the modem so your router's WAN Ethernet MAC address is the only MAC address your cable modem can see. Then your router will use NAT to make all your Internet traffic from all your clients look like it all came from your router.

Answer (score 0):

It should work as long as the Cable Modem can hand out local IP Addresses via DHCP. You will probably get strange addresses handed out because they will come direct from your ISP.

DHCP needs to exist on one of the devices on your network and is very important on a basic network as it allows clients to automatically get IP addresses and connect. The Modem might work as is but is not the most desirable.

A better and more secure alternative to setup a Network is to connect a WiFi Router between the PC's and the Cable Modem.

Some Cable Modems serve Dual Purpose as Modems and WiFi Routers. A Modem like this would already have DHCP built in and be ready to go for your local network. You usually get these WiFi enabled Modems supplied by your ISP.

Answer (score 0):

What you need here is a router.  Cable modems normally note the first device they see and speak only to that device.  Hence you must provide a single device for it to talk to that hands out local IP addresses to the other devices--a router.

Note that there are cable modems with built-in router but obviously you do not have one.